# Setting attributes with dashes in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to set multiple attributes in d3 but I get an error for the stroke width attribute due to the dash.

I can get around this by chaining another attribute's call but I would like to keep them all in one call if I can.

Is this possible?

```
var edges = svg.selectAll("line")
        .data(data.edges)
        .enter()
        .append("line")
        .attr("stroke", "#ccc")
        .attr("stroke-width", 3};
```

Comment: My apologies about the off topic. Should have asked on stackoverflow.

Comment: I don't think that it's off topic at all. It contains working code, and asks for a better way to do the same thing.

Comment: "Is this possible?" does not make an on-topic Code Review question. "This seems to work, but is it a good idea?", on the other hand, would be a reasonable question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use a string literal as identifier to use the object literal syntax. Note also that there is a colon after the identifier, not a comma:

```
var edges = svg.selectAll("line")
    .data(data.edges)
    .enter()
    .append("line")
    .attr({
        stroke: "#ccc",
        'stroke-width': 3
    });
```